# When install python-3.12.0-amd64, it shows erro 2203, how to solve it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation

this is my step to use the python-3.12.0-amd64:

1. i ran it
2. i choose  `add python.exe to path`
3. i choose Install Now
4. then it showed `the installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2203.`

ps: i run this installer in `Run as an administrator`
this is how the erro 2203 show

then i check erro 2203 means `Invalid ciphertext password`
but i cannot understand why i install a python should consider password?
And i also find nothing could sovle my problem

Comment: Finaly i add it to path instead of using its installer, which sloved my problem, but i still have no idea of this error